# List all files from a directory recursively with Java

Tags: java, file-io

I have this function that prints the name of all the files in a directory recursively. The problem is that my code is very slow because it has to access a remote network device with every iteration.

My plan is to first load all the files from the directory recursively and then after that go through all files with the regex to filter out all the files I don't want. Is there a better solution?

```java
public static printFnames(String sDir) {
    File[] faFiles = new File(sDir).listFiles();
    for (File file : faFiles) {
        if (file.getName().matches("^(.*?)")) {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            printFnames(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a test. Later on I'm not going to use the code like this; instead I'm going to add the path and modification date of every file which matches an advanced regex to an array.

Comment: ... what's the question? Are you just looking for validation that this code will work?

Comment: No, I know this code works but it's very slow and it feels like it's stupid access the filesystem and get the contents for every subdirectory instead of getting everything at once.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursively list files in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java)

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Assuming this is actual production code you'll be writing, then I suggest using the solution to this sort of thing that's already been solved - [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/), specifically [`FileUtils.listFiles()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles%28java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter%29). It handles nested directories, filters (based on name, modification time, etc).

For example, for your regex:

```
Collection files = FileUtils.listFiles(
  dir, 
  new RegexFileFilter("^(.*?)"), 
  DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY
);
```

This will recursively search for files matching the `^(.*?)` regex, returning the results as a collection.

It's worth noting that this will be no faster than rolling your own code, it's doing the same thing - trawling a filesystem in Java is just slow. The difference is, the Apache Commons version will have no bugs in it.

Comment: I looked there and from that I would use http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html to get all the file from the directory and subdirectories and then search through the files so that they match my regex. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah problem it takes over an hour to scan the folder and doing that every time I start the program to check for updates is extremely annoying. Would it be faster if I wrote this part of the program in C and the rest in Java and if so would it be any significant difference? For now I changed the code on the if isdir line and added so that the directory also have to match a regex to be included in the search. I see that in your example it says  DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY, I guesss I could have a regex filter there.

Comment: writing it using native calls would absolutely make it faster - FindFirstFile/FineNextFile allows you to query the file attributes without having to make a separate call for it - this can have massive implications for higher latency networks.  Java's approach to this is horribly inefficient.

Comment: @hanzallah-afgan: Both the question and the answer is over 5 years old. There's been two major Java releases during the time that have past so you might wan't to investigate newer features such as Java 7 NIO.

Comment: Yes, But that wasn't bad too. BTW You are prodding right too.

Comment: @skaffman How can I adapt the above code for use in display subdirectories and files from present directory?

Comment: this answer is very deprecated

Comment: Only use FileUtils if you are aware of and accept the performance hit: https://github.com/brettryan/io-recurse-tests. Native java8 alternatives allow for a terse and more efficient notation e.g.: `Files.walk(Paths.get("/etc")).filter(Files::isRegularFile).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 83):

In Java 8, it's a 1-liner via [`Files.find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#find-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.util.function.BiPredicate-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) with an arbitrarily large depth (eg `999`) and [`BasicFileAttributes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html) of [`isRegularFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html#isRegularFile--)

```
public static printFnames(String sDir) {
    Files.find(Paths.get(sDir), 999, (p, bfa) -> bfa.isRegularFile()).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

To add more filtering, enhance the lambda, for example all jpg files modified in the last 24 hours:

```
(p, bfa) -> bfa.isRegularFile()
  && p.getFileName().toString().matches(".*\\.jpg")
  && bfa.lastModifiedTime().toMillis() > System.currentMillis() - 86400000
```

Comment: I suggest to always use those Files methods which returns Stream in try-with-resources blocks: otherwise you'll keep the resource opened

Comment: Don't terminal operations call close on stream itself?

Comment: @Dragas yes. My consumer is only a simple example; in real life you would do something more useful.

Comment: This is what the documentation of `Files.find` says:
`API Note:
This method must be used within a try-with-resources statement or similar control structure to ensure that the stream's open directories are closed promptly after the stream's operations have completed.`

Edit: Terminal operations DO NOT close streams:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/27382060/2173948]

Answer (score 30):

This is a very simple recursive method to get all files from a given root.

It uses the Java 7 NIO Path class.

```
private List<String> getFileNames(List<String> fileNames, Path dir) {
    try(DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir)) {
        for (Path path : stream) {
            if(path.toFile().isDirectory()) {
                getFileNames(fileNames, path);
            } else {
                fileNames.add(path.toAbsolutePath().toString());
                System.out.println(path.getFileName());
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fileNames;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

With Java 7, a faster way to walk through a directory tree was introduced with the `Paths` and `Files` functionality. They're much faster than the "old" `File` way.

This would be the code to walk through and check path names with a regular expression:

```
public final void test() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    final Path rootDir = Paths.get("path to your directory where the walk starts");

    // Walk thru mainDir directory
    Files.walkFileTree(rootDir, new FileVisitor<Path>() {
        // First (minor) speed up. Compile regular expression pattern only one time.
        private Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)");

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path path,
                BasicFileAttributes atts) throws IOException {

            boolean matches = pattern.matcher(path.toString()).matches();

            // TODO: Put here your business logic when matches equals true/false

            return (matches)? FileVisitResult.CONTINUE:FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path, BasicFileAttributes mainAtts)
                throws IOException {

            boolean matches = pattern.matcher(path.toString()).matches();

            // TODO: Put here your business logic when matches equals true/false

            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path path,
                IOException exc) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path path, IOException exc)
                throws IOException {
            exc.printStackTrace();

            // If the root directory has failed it makes no sense to continue
            return path.equals(rootDir)? FileVisitResult.TERMINATE:FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Nice answer :), theres also an implemented class of it called "SimpleFileVisitor", if you don't need all the implemented fucntions, you can just Override the needed functions.

Answer (score 14):

The fast way to get the content of a directory using Java 7 NIO:

```
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;

...

Path dir = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(filePath);
DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir);
for (Path path : stream) {
   System.out.println(path.getFileName());
}
stream.close();
```

Comment: Nice but only gets files for one directory.  If you want to see all sub directories see my alternative answer.

Comment: `Files.newDirectoryStream` can throw an IOException. I suggest wrapping that line in a Java7 try-with-statement so that the stream will always be closed for you (exception or not, without the need for a `finally`). See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739362/java7-try-with-resources-statement-advantage

Answer (score 12):

Java's interface for reading filesystem folder contents is not very performant (as you've discovered).  JDK 7 fixes this with a completely new interface for this sort of thing, which should bring native level performance to these sorts of operations.

The core issue is that Java makes a native system call for every single file.  On a low latency interface, this is not that big of a deal - but on a network with even moderate latency, it really adds up.  If you profile your algorithm above, you'll find that the bulk of the time is spent in the pesky isDirectory() call - that's because you are incurring a round trip for every single call to isDirectory().  Most modern OSes can provide this sort of information when the list of files/folders was originally requested (as opposed to querying each individual file path for it's properties).

If you can't wait for JDK7, one strategy for addressing this latency is to go multi-threaded and use an ExecutorService with a maximum # of threads to perform your recursion.  It's not great (you have to deal with locking of your output data structures), but it'll be a heck of a lot faster than doing this single threaded.

In all of your discussions about this sort of thing, I highly recommend that you compare against the best you could do using native code (or even a command line script that does roughly the same thing).  Saying that it takes an hour to traverse a network structure doesn't really mean that much.  Telling us that you can do it native in 7 second, but it takes an hour in Java will get people's attention.

Comment: Java 7 is now there so an example on how to do it in Java 7 would be helpful. Or at least a link. Or a class name to search for on google. — this is «stackoverflow» and not «theoretical cs» after all ;-) .

Comment: well lets see...  My original post was in March 2010...  It's now January 2012...  And I just checked my equipment inventory history, and I don't see myself having had a time machine back in March '10, so I think I'm probably justified in answering without giving explicit example ;-)

Comment: @Martin [These are the docs you're looking for.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.util.Set,%20int,%20java.nio.file.FileVisitor%29)

Answer (score 7):

This will work just fine and it’s recursive.

```
File root = new File("ROOT PATH");
for (File file : root.listFiles())
{
    getFilesRecursive(file);
}


private static void getFilesRecursive(File pFile)
{
    for(File files : pFile.listFiles())
    {
        if(files.isDirectory())
        {
            getFilesRecursive(files);
        }
        else
        {
            // Do your thing
            //
            // You can either save in HashMap and
            // use it as per your requirement
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer if you want something that works with java <7.

Answer (score 4):

I personally like this version of FileUtils. Here's an example that finds all mp3s or flacs in a directory or any of its subdirectories:

```
String[] types = {"mp3", "flac"};
Collection<File> files2 = FileUtils.listFiles(/path/to/your/dir, types , true);
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work fine

```
public void displayAll(File path){      
    if(path.isFile()){
        System.out.println(path.getName());
    }else{
        System.out.println(path.getName());         
        File files[] = path.listFiles();
        for(File dirOrFile: files){
            displayAll(dirOrFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Mam's, could you clarify how your answer is an improvement or alternative to the many existing answers?

Comment: Where was this copied from?

Answer (score 2):

**Java 8**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Path start = Paths.get("C:\\data\\");
        try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(start, Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            List<String> collect = stream
                .map(String::valueOf)
                .sorted()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

            collect.forEach(System.out::println);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Where was this copied from?

Answer (score 1):

This function will probably list all the file name and its path from its directory and its subdirectories.

```
public void listFile(String pathname) {
    File f = new File(pathname);
    File[] listfiles = f.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < listfiles.length; i++) {
        if (listfiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            File[] internalFile = listfiles[i].listFiles();
            for (int j = 0; j < internalFile.length; j++) {
                System.out.println(internalFile[j]);
                if (internalFile[j].isDirectory()) {
                    String name = internalFile[j].getAbsolutePath();
                    listFile(name);
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(listfiles[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This example does not take into account the fact that listFiles() method, can and will return null. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()

Answer (score 1):

```
public class GetFilesRecursive {
    public static List <String> getFilesRecursively(File dir){
        List <String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (File fObj : dir.listFiles()) {
            if(fObj.isDirectory()) {
                ls.add(String.valueOf(fObj));
                ls.addAll(getFilesRecursively(fObj));               
            } else {
                ls.add(String.valueOf(fObj));       
            }
        }

        return ls;
    }
    public static List <String> getListOfFiles(String fullPathDir) {
        List <String> ls = new ArrayList<String> ();
        File f = new File(fullPathDir);
        if (f.exists()) {
            if(f.isDirectory()) {
                ls.add(String.valueOf(f));
                ls.addAll(getFilesRecursively(f));
            }
        } else {
            ls.add(fullPathDir);
        }
        return ls;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List <String> ls = getListOfFiles("/Users/srinivasab/Documents");
        for (String file:ls) {
            System.out.println(file);
        }
        System.out.println(ls.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Where was this copied from?

Answer (score 0):

> it feels like it's stupid access the
>   filesystem and get the contents for
>   every subdirectory instead of getting
>   everything at once.

Your feeling is wrong. That's how filesystems work. There is no faster way (except when you have to do this repeatedly or for different patterns, you can cache all the file paths in memory, but then you have to deal with cache invalidation i.e. what happens when files are added/removed/renamed while the app runs).

Comment: Thing is I want to load all files of a certain type with a certain name format into a library which is presented to the user and everytime the app is started the library is supposed to be updated but it takes forever to update the library. Only solution I got is to run the update in the background but it's still annoying that it takes so long time until all the new files are loaded. There must be a better way to do it. Or at least a better way to update the database. It feels stupid for it to go through all the files it have already gone through onces. Is there a way to only find updates fast.

Comment: @Hultner: Java 7 will include a facility for getting notified of filesystem updates, but that would still only work while the app is running, so unless you want to have a background service run all the time, it would not help. There might be special issues with network shares as Kevin describes, but as long as you depend on scanning through the entire directory tree, there really is no better way.

Comment: Perhaps you could create some index files. If there's a way to check the directory size you could simply scan for new files when the size changes.

Comment: @James: there is no way to check the directory size. The size of a directory is obtained by getting the size for each file and adding them up, in all filesystems I am aware of. Actually, the question "what is the size of this directory?" does not even neccessarily make sense at all if you consider hardlinks.

Comment: You're right. I still feel that some caching and/or fingerprinting could speed up the process.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know isDirectory() is quite a slow method. I'm finding it quite slow in my file browser. I'll be looking into a library to replace it with native code.

Answer (score 0):

The more efficient way I found in dealing with millions of folders and files is to capture a directory listing through a DOS command in some file and parse it.

Once you have parsed the data then you can do analysis and compute statistics.

Comment: Yes, creating a file index can make it thousands of times faster. A more suitable tool is [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep), say, through [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) (much lighter and faster to install than [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin)). Though you still have to pay the initial price of the creating the first index. There is also the problem of keeping it updated. Though how does that answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;

public class MultiFolderReading {

    public void checkNoOfFiles (String filename) throws IOException {

        File dir = new File(filename);
        File files[] = dir.listFiles(); // Files array stores the list of files

        for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
        {
            if(files[i].isFile()) // Check whether files[i] is file or directory
            {
                System.out.println("File::" + files[i].getName());
                System.out.println();

            }
            else if(files[i].isDirectory())
            {
                System.out.println("Directory::" + files[i].getName());
                System.out.println();
                checkNoOfFiles(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        MultiFolderReading mf = new MultiFolderReading();
        String str = "E:\\file";
        mf.checkNoOfFiles(str);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation, too.

Comment: Where was this copied from?

Answer (score 0):

In [Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) you don't have to wait for a Collection to be returned to you, but can actually iterate over the files. It is easy to imagine a `IDoSomethingWithThisFile` interface in the signature of the below function:

```
public static void collectFilesInDir(File dir) {
    TreeTraverser<File> traverser = Files.fileTreeTraverser();
    FluentIterable<File> filesInPostOrder = traverser.preOrderTraversal(dir);
    for (File f: filesInPostOrder)
        System.out.printf("File: %s\n", f.getPath());
}
```

[TreeTraverser](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeTraverser.html) also allows you to between various traversal styles.

Answer (score 0):

Another optimized code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GetFilesRecursive {
    public static List <String> getFilesRecursively(File dir){
        List <String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (dir.isDirectory())
            for (File fObj : dir.listFiles()) {
                if(fObj.isDirectory()) {
                    ls.add(String.valueOf(fObj));
                    ls.addAll(getFilesRecursively(fObj));               
                } else {
                    ls.add(String.valueOf(fObj));       
                }
            }
        else
            ls.add(String.valueOf(dir));

        return ls;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List <String> ls = getFilesRecursively(new File("/Users/srinivasab/Documents"));
        for (String file:ls) {
            System.out.println(file);
        }
        System.out.println(ls.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? This will be very useful for understanding. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One more example of listing files and directories using Java 8 `filter`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.println("Files!!");
        try {
            Files.walk(Paths.get("."))
                    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                    .filter(c ->
                            c.getFileName().toString().substring(c.getFileName().toString().length()-4).contains(".jpg")
                            ||
                            c.getFileName().toString().substring(c.getFileName().toString().length()-5).contains(".jpeg")
                    )
                    .forEach(System.out::println);

        } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("No jpeg or jpg files");
        }

        System.out.println("\nDirectories!!\n");
        try {
            Files.walk(Paths.get("."))
                    .filter(Files::isDirectory)
                    .forEach(System.out::println);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("No Jpeg files");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Test folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGnB4.png)

I tested some method with 60,000 files in 284 folders on Windows 11:

```java
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Path path = Paths.get("E:\\书籍");

        // 1.walkFileTree
        long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
                // if(pathMatcher.matches(file))
                // files.add(file.toFile());

                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
                // System.out.println(dir.getFileName());
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException e) {
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

        });
        long end1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // 2. newDirectoryStream
        long start2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        search(path.toFile());
        long end2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // 3. listFiles
        long start3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        getFileNames(path);
        long end3 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("\r执行耗时:" + (end1 - start1));
        System.out.println("\r执行耗时:" + (end2 - start2));
        System.out.println("\r执行耗时:" + (end3 - start3));
    }


    private static void getFileNames(Path dir) {
        try(DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir)) {
            for (Path path : stream) {
                if(Files.isDirectory(path)) {
                    getFileNames(path);
                }
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void search(File file) {
        Queue<File> q = new LinkedList<>();
        q.offer(file);
        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                for (File childfile : q.poll().listFiles()) {
                    // System.out.println(childfile.getName());
                    if (childfile.isDirectory()) {
                        q.offer(childfile);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Result (milliseconds)：

| walkFileTree | listFiles | newDirectoryStream |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 68 | 451 | 493 |
| 64 | 464 | 482 |
| 61 | 478 | 457 |
| 67 | 477 | 488 |
| 59 | 474 | 466 |

Known performance issues：

1. From [Kevin Day's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534632/list-all-files-from-a-directory-recursively-with-java/2535558#2535558):

   > If you profile your algorithm above, you'll find that the bulk of the time is spent in the pesky isDirectory() call - that's because you are incurring a round trip for every single call to isDirectory().
2. listfiles() will create new File Object for every entry

Comment: It's nice to see that people are still answering this 12 years later. Many of the problems I originally had was due to limitations in Java 1.5/1.6, I think the real issue was resolved in Java 1.7 and forward, with the introduction of the (then) new file system APIs.