# MultiResourceParitioner in Spring Batch to accept files from multiple folders

Tags: spring-batch

I have the following configuration in the file  **dataloader.properties**

```
filepath = /xx
exchange = M00,M01,MF2,MF3
```

I need the MultiResourcePartitioner to process the files from all these folders such as

```
/xx/M00/*
/xx/M01/*
/xx/MF2/*
/xx/MF3/*
```

There can be other folders under `/xx` ,  but it should process only the files from folder  `M00,M01,MF2,MF3`

```
<bean id="filepartitioner" class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.MultiResourcePartitioner">
    <property name="resources" value="classpath:./${filepath}" />
</bean>
```

kindly let me know , how to do this in spring batch .I had a look at a `filesystemresource` and `ResourcesItemReader`  api , but no idea how to inject it to the `MultiResourceParitioner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**simple solution - if possible at all**
if the pattern stays stable you could try it with

```
<bean id="filepartitioner" class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.MultiResourcePartitioner">
    <property name="resources" value="classpath:./${filepath}/M*/*" />
</bean>
```

**customized MultiResourcePartitioner - filters folders**

```
public class CustomM... extends MultiResourcePartitioner {
    // constructor with filePath and exchange argument
    // convert exchange argument to list of folder patterns,
    // or let it convert by spring magic
    // use one of the "list all files.." methods from below
    // call setResources(...)
}

<bean id="filepartitioner" class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.CustomMultiResourcePartitioner">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${filePath}" />
    <!-- spring can convert comma separated values to array and list
         just look into the spring documentation -->
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${exchange}" />
</bean>
```

a working example is available on [my github repo](https://github.com/langmi) at https://github.com/langmi/spring-batch-examples-playground/blob/4e733dce09daffca1c10d4907f410ac5bead6887/src/main/resources/spring/batch/job/file-multiresourcepartitioner-filter-folders-factory-job.xml, check *file-multiresourcepartitioner-filter-folders-job.xml*

**more pluggable solution: Factory which creates the Resources for the MultiResourcePartitioner**

```
public class FilterFactory {
  public static Resource[] getInstance(final String filePath, final List<String> acceptedFolders) {
    final List<FileSystemResource> files = new ArrayList<FileSystemResource>();
    yourListAllFilesButFilterFoldersMethod(files, filePath, acceptedFolders)
    return files.toArray(new Resource[0]);
  }
}

<bean id="resources" class="de.langmi.spring.batch.examples.playground.resource.FiltersFoldersResourceFactory" factory-method="getInstance">
    <constructor-arg name="filePath" type="java.lang.String" value="${filePath}" />
    <constructor-arg name="acceptedFolders" type="java.util.List" value="${acceptedFolders}" />
</bean>
```

a working example is available on [my github repo](https://github.com/langmi) at https://github.com/langmi/spring-batch-examples/tree/master/playground/src/main/resources/spring/batch/job, check *file-multiresourcepartitioner-filter-folders-factory-job.xml*

you can pick the method to set the Resources array from [List all files from a directory recursively with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534632/list-all-files-from-a-directory-recursively-with-java) and similar solutions across the net, only thing left is the filter, there is one solution in the link provided

Comment: thanks .pattern changes . should i call setResource from constructor.

Comment: i do not understand, is this a question?

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked . now i got idea after seeing factory method in xml config .