# how to copy files to specific path?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a List which contains File type Object.
Eg.List < File > copyFile = new ArrayList < File >();
Now I want Copy this copyFile to d:\\demo\\ location.
AnyOne can tell me how to this ?
I know how to copy file from path to path.

```
Files.copy(src, dst, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: you want to search whether folder name starts with N33, N44 or N55 something like that?

Comment: This is a task where using recursion is a natural fit. Look for tree traversal on google.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534632/list-all-files-from-a-directory-recursively-with-java

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help  you to list all the folder names

```
 class Folder {
      boolean isFile;
      String folderName;
      List<Folder> subFolders = new ArrayList<Folder>();
    }

class ListF {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
     File fname = new File("D:\\Demo\\");
     Folder obj = new Folder();
     if (fname.isDirectory()) {
        File[] fileNames;
        fileNames = fname.listFiles();
        for (i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
           obj.subFolders.add(fileNames[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("The list is " + obj.subFolders);
     }
   }
}
```

To copy directory below code is usefull

```
File source = new File("D:\\folder-path\\folder1");
File desc = new File("D:\\folder-path\\new folder");
FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, desc);
```

Comment: wat is FuileUtils? This is not work

Comment: @vijayk [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

Comment: To use FileUtils you have to require commons.io jar, Solve my problem..thanks brother to give fabulous reply...:P