# Recursively moving files from one directory to another only partially completes

Tags: java, fileutils, java.nio.file

Based on an answer to: [List all files from a directory recursively with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534632/list-all-files-from-a-directory-recursively-with-java)

I have written a little Filemover which will recursively move every file from a directory and place them in the top level of another directory. But for some reason, the code doesn't move all the files. I switched to using Files.move() but while definitely worth while the code is still not walking the directory tree properly. Now I am getting a **java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException** while trying to move the files.

The stack trace says that its an unknown source, yet when I look to see if the file is there it is. I have isolated the problem to **Files.move()** but I can't seems to fix it. I have tried both **getPath()** and **getAbsolutePath()**. What's even weirder I use a similar method in my sorting routine and it works fine. The only difference is that my source directory has no subdirectories.

I have solved the partial tree walk. It was caused because my ImageFilter only had lower case extensions and the filter needed to be case sensitive. So I fixed it here.

Okay, I switched my little Filemover back to **file.renameTo()** and it works properly now. It's just a testing tool for randomly moving files into a drop directory for my image sorter so it's not worth figuring out why I was getting **no such file exceptions**. I was just modifying it to work recursively so it could be used to reverse a sort if someone used the wrong sorting routine on a bunch of images.

Thanks for all your help :)

I have 3 classes

```
 import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;



import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.DirectoryFileFilter;

import ca.fotonow.p3software.ImageFileFilter;

public class PSFileUtils {
    public static Collection<File> listfiles(String directory) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File dir= new File (directory);
        dir.mkdirs(); //create directory if it doesn't exist.
        Collection<File> files= FileUtils.listFiles(dir,new ImageFileFilter(),DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY);


        return files;
    }
   }
```

Filter Class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;

import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter;

public class ImageFileFilter implements IOFileFilter {
    private final String filetypes[]= new String[] {"jpeg", "JPEG","jpg","JPG","tif","TIF","tiff","TIFF","raw","RAW"}; 
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        for (String ext: filetypes) {
            if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(ext)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

The main class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;

public class FileMover {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Move random number of files from one directory args[0] to another directory args[1]
    //directories can be relative
    //Repeats randomly until files are gone

    String dir1=args[0];
    String dir2=args[1];



    Collection<File> files=PSFileUtils.listfiles(dir1);

    for (File file: files) {

        File newfile=new File(dir2+"/"+file.getName());

        try {
        Files.move(file.toPath(),newfile.toPath(), REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
        System.out.println((new Date()).getTime()+ " "+ newfile.getName());

        Random generator =new Random(new Date().getTime());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(generator.nextInt(5000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Any idea of what I have wrong?

Comment: Yes, one thing is obvious: the first two code examples are identical ;)

Comment: Not any more. My ctrl-c must not of taken on the one copy.

Comment: Are you sure all the source file names will be unique in the target directory? Otherwise the duplicates won't be moved.

Comment: Also, allow me a somewhat off topic comment: do you actually need to do this in Java? Because in the shell it's a one liner: `find source/dir/ -type f -exec mv -t destination/dir/ {} +`

Comment: @Tobia Yes in this case they are all unique

Comment: @Tobia no I don't need java but find won't work on a windows machine.

Comment: Many things won't work on a windows machine ;-) j/k. My point was, if you compare the actual effort needed to solve your problem with an appropriate tool (one line of shell commands) with the effort you're putting into your Java solution (many pages of code) what I gather is that you're using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: In this case the tool was already written to randomly seed an input directory for testing my application. All I did was modify the listFiles() to run recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though @nitegazer is correct I should have used **`Files.move()`** instead of **`File.renameTo()`**. It turns out that that was not the reason for the partial file tree walk. The file tree walk was failing because the filter is case sensitive and I only provided lower case versions of the file extensions.

I did have a problem with a little script that I use to randomly fill the input hopper for testing the sorter but that just a test script and works fine with **`File.renameTo()`**.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming the file might not move the file, according to the javadocs:

> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname already exists. The return value should always be checked to make sure that the rename operation was successful.

Try `java.nio.file.Files.move()` instead.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem because I have been moving files fine from directory to directory but I will try it.

Comment: I trying to use Files.move(file.toPath(),newfile.toPath(),REPLACE_EXISTING); but I am getting an error on REPLACE_EXISTING saying it can't be resolved.

Comment: Okay this seems to solve the partial move but now files are failing because files.move says they don't exist which is new.

Comment: Actually using renameTo() was not my problem at all. The extensions were case sensitive and that's why they were not all moved.