# Files.newDirectoryStream with filter recursive

Tags: java, file, recursion, nio, directorystream

I had the following code:

```
Path dir = Paths.get("My root dir/Folder1");
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*.xml")) {
        for (Path entry : stream) {
            // Do something
        }
} catch (IOException e) {
        //
}
```

Now the folder structure changed and I can have both:

```
My root dir
-- Folder1
---- MyFile.xml
```

or

```
My root dir
-- Folder1_MyFile.xml
```

So I would like to be able to use the following code:

```
Path dir = Paths.get("My root dir/Folder1");
String pattern = "Folder1/*.xml"; // or "Folder1_*.xml"
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, pattern)) {
        for (Path entry : stream) {
            // Do something
        }
}
```

In this case, I would only have to change the `pattern` variable, with a value of `"Folder1/*.xml"` or `"Folder1_*.xml"`.
The first one (`"Folder1/*.xml"`) doesn't work because `Files.newDirectoryStream` is not recursive and only try to match the files/folders at the first level in the `dir` folder.

Is there any way to use the `Files.newDirectoryStream(Path dir, String glob)` method this way (filtering files recursively) or do I have to make myself a recursive method that retrieves ALL the files/folders and manually filter them ?
(I would rather not use external libraries)

Thanks.

Comment: And I have already seen the question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987214/recursively-list-all-files-within-a-directory-using-nio-file-directorystream) but I would like not to list ALL the files but filter them using the already existing newDirectoryStream(Path dir, String glob) method.

Comment: What prevents you from using the method with the `glob` in the recursive approach in the linked question?

Comment: First, my question was to know if it was possible to use the Files.newDirectoryStream(Path dir, String glob) method in a certain way to get what I wanted, without writing a recursive method (what I will do if the answer is that nothing else exists).

Comment: Second, I cannot directly use the solution in this link just adding the glob since the glob cannot be a path anyway. Yes I already knew I would have to write something like this if there is no way to use the Files.newDirectoryStream(Path dir, String glob) or similar with a path in the glob.

Comment: I suggest asking a new more carefully targeted question.