# Java 8 DirectoryStream and glob for subdirectories

Tags: java, java-8

Hello I have the following directory structure:

```
/root
   file1.js
   /folder1
      file2.js
```

I'm using the following code:

```
Path dir = Paths.get("root");
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir,"**.js")) {
    for (Path file: stream) {
        System.out.println(file.getFileName());
    }
} catch (IOException | DirectoryIteratorException x) {
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

I want to return all `.js` files in `root` and `folder1`.

If I use `*.js` returns `file1.js` , but if I use `**.js` returns the same `file1.js`.

Why is not returning the `folder1/file2.js` ?

According to official documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html#glob

> Two asterisks, **, works like * but crosses directory boundaries. This
>   syntax is generally used for matching complete paths

Thanks

Comment: I don't see the documentation you cite [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.String-) (Oracle java 8 documentation)

Comment: I don't think `DirectoryStream` recurs through directories. Do that yourself or use `Files#walkFileTree`.

Comment: @lucasvw I've updated the post with documentation link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534632/list-all-files-from-a-directory-recursively-with-java