# List files from folder and subfolders recursively in JMeter

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter, beanshell

I use `BeanShell Sampler` in `JMeter` to list all the files from a folder. It lists files only from directory and unable to do the same in subdirectories

```
File folder = new File("C:\\_private\\Files\\input");

File[] files = folder.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isFile();
    }
});

for (int i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
    vars.put("file_" + i, files[i].getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List all files from a directory recursively with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534632/list-all-files-from-a-directory-recursively-with-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move to use [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with the following code using [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles(java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter)):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
List<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(new File("C:\\_private\\Files\\input"), null, true);
```

Notice to replace `files.length` with `files.size()`:

```
for (int i=0; i < files.size(); i++) {
    vars.put("file_" + i, files[i].getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Comment: how is FileUtils for BeanShell added to the classpath, though?

Comment: @Thufir you can download from https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi

Comment: I meant, from BeanShell, how is the downloaded JAR added?  Maybe seperate q.

Comment: @Thufir you need to add jar to JMeter classpath

Answer (score 2):

[Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting mainly because [Groovy performance is much better](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) comparing to other scripting options

Groovy in its turn provides [File.eachFileRecurse()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#eachFileRecurse(groovy.io.FileType,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) function which is exactly what you're looking for.

Example code:

```
def index = 1

new File('c:/apps/jmeter/bin').eachFileRecurse(groovy.io.FileType.FILES) {
    vars.put('file_' + index, it.getAbsolutePath())
    index++
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do it recursively. You can list all the directories the same way you did for the files, and then call the function you created, [recursively](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/). When you then call the function with your initial file, it will traverse the tree structure and give you all files in a list. To add to a list use `addAll`.

```
def listFiles(File folder) {
    ... // Recursive function
}
```