# is there a way to use the file path instead of file name in BufferedReader?

Tags: java, path, bufferedreader

I would like to add the path instead of the file name in BufferedReader?
I want to use the path because I want the code to pickup any file that has the name "audit" in that specific folder.

So I am currently using this method below, but it only works when I add the absolute path.

`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException {
    List<String> stngFile = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader bfredr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader
            ("file path"));



    String text = bfredr.readLine();
    while (text != null) {
        stngFile.add(text);
        text = bfredr.readLine();
    }
    bfredr.close();
    String[] array = stngFile.toArray(new String[0]);

    Arrays.toString(array);
    for (String eachstring : array) {
         System.out.println(eachstring);
    }

}
```

`

I am new to programming any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need to open each file that matches your pattern in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

FileReader also has a constructor that takes a file. You can create a file object using a URI or a string for the path. You could use a FileFilter or just check if each file matches the name you provide, which is how i would do it:

To get all files in a folder you can use `folder.listFiles()`.
You can then use `file.getName().contains("audit")` to check if the filename contains "audit".

Note that this is case sensitive, to ignore case you would just use `file.getName().toLowerCase().contains("audit")` (make sure the string you check here, in this case "audit", is always lower case).

As pointed out by g00se, you will also have to check if file is actually a file and not a directory using `file.isFile()`

Then in a loop you just read out to content of each file that matches the above condition seperately.

If you need the files in all the subfolders aswell, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534632/list-all-files-from-a-directory-recursively-with-java).

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File folder = new File("C:\\MyFolder"); // the folder containing all the files you are looking for
    for (File file : folder.listFiles()) { // loop through each file in that folder
        if (file.getName().contains("audit") && file.isFile()) { // check if it contains audit in its name
            // your previous code for reading out the file content
            BufferedReader bfredr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            List<String> stngFile = new ArrayList<String>();
            String text = bfredr.readLine();
            while (text != null) {
                stngFile.add(text);
                text = bfredr.readLine();
            }
            bfredr.close();
            String[] array = stngFile.toArray(new String[0]);
            
            Arrays.toString(array);
            for (String eachstring : array) {
                 System.out.println(eachstring);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `if (file.getName().contains("audit") && file.isFile())` Filter can be used too

Comment: You're right, let me adjust.