# java program to list files with their path

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recursively list files in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java)

Java program to list all files in a drive along with the path of that file.....is it possible? how?

Comment: Are you looking for a "program"? Or how to program it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Use File.listFiles() and iterate over directories recursively.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, File has a method [list](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29). If you'd like to use recurrent searching, you might be interested in [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html).

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File[] roots = File.listRoots();

        for (File root : roots) {
            showFolderRecursively(root);
        }
    }

    private static void showFolderRecursively(File root) {

        System.out.println(root.getAbsolutePath());
        File[] files = root.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if ( file.isFile() ) {
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                showFolderRecursively(file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @luckas : progrmm itself