# get files located on computer

Tags: java

Is java able to access directories and their contents located on the computer it's run from? I know that there is a JFileChooser (Where the user can select files), and I know that you can store/open files with direct paths. But can java get all files and directories conntained with a folder?

**Can java list file contents of directories stored on a hard drive?**

Comment: Yes, it can. So long as the account used to execute the application has the right permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the files under any directory like this:

```
File[] files = new File("/some/path").listFiles();
```

You might also be interested in how to [recursively list files in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can.

So long as the account used to execute the application has the right permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can. In addition to what Oded said, in the case of applets, you need to explicitly grant access to read and write to a hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filepath to a directory you want and you can do something like:

```
File directory = new File("PATH TO DIRECTORY");
File [] contents;
if (directory.isDirectory()) {
    contents = directory.listFiles();  // returns an array containing the file and directory abstract paths.
}
```