# How to scan storage to read all .pdf?

Tags: android

I want to scan the internal & external storage to read all PDFs and then display them in a list to choose from.

Can anybody pls tell me how to do this?

Regards,
Monali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use as lobner has written standart libraries like http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html
and to set .pdf as a filer:
http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter.html

Answer (score 2):

It being android, you have full Java capabilities, thus there are extensive resources, even here on StackOverflow, on how to list files.

For an example: [Recursively list files in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java/2056258#2056258)

Do that, and ex. use an if-statement that only lists files with an .pdf extension. Then you are good to go :)

EDIT: For system responsiveness, you may also want to do it in a different thread, than the UI thread. Take a look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and the supporting example about [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to recursively look through the files on the SDCard using the standard file functions like isDirectory() etc. and then check the extension of the file for PDF.