# How to list all the folders and sub folders in a directory without using recursion

Tags: c#

Please tell me how to write program to list all the folders and subfolders in a directory without using recursion and any library functions.(in C#)?

Comment: Use a stack as illustrated in the StackBasedIteration example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
var dirList = Directory.GetDirectories("directotyPath", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

This will return all directories in the given `directotyPath`.

Comment: This is originally what I posted as a comment, but see above where he asks for it in a way that doesn't use library functions.

Answer (score 0):

Stack or queue both can be used with searching algorithms for such purpose if you don't want to list all directories using recursion.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6776380/3747199) is demonstration of your requirement using stack. The solution is in Java, you can understand the work flow and convert it to `c#` by yourself