# File listing in Java. A fresh look

Tags: java, string, file, recursion, directory

The question is rather simple, but my brain boils :(((
I know, that i should recursive function, but I can't organize it properely,
because I'm limited by the types(it's a requirment)

```
public String[] getFiles(String initialDir) {}
```

First in my code I get the list of files and directories of initialDir
then i go through the elements and look up for directories with the help of

```
.isDirectory()
```

and then I try to organize recursion, something like:

```
String [] buf = getFiles(Filelist[i].toString());
```

and here come troubles.

The main problem is, determining the size of obtained data and allocating
the necessary array of String [] type and further writing all recursion results
and first-call results to the resulting array of String [] type.

It really annoys me, so i need a fresh look from a side (maybe someone will help with
code in the function).

Thanks to all!

Comment: Do you have to return `String[]`, could you instead return `List<String>`? That way you don't have to know up-front how many items you're going to require.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java

Comment: @Peter, no i can't return List<String>, if i could, the solution was much simpler

Comment: Are you allowed to use `ArrayList` or other types of collections internally? This is homework, right?

Comment: @Helgus You can't use List<String> AT ALL, or only return it? Also, can you create a different method which will return List<String>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list in the body of your method then convert it to an array:

```
public String[] getFiles(String initialDir) {
   List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
   ...
       files.add(aLovelyFile);
   ...
       String[] moarFiles = getFiles(aLovelyDirectory);
       files.addAll(Arrays.asList(moarFiles));
   ...
   return files.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: thank you a LOT!!!!! i've tried to use collection, but then i lost in me own code and indexes...

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't homework, look at Apache Commons, specifically [FileUtils#ListFiles](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles%28java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter%29):

> Finds files within a given directory (and optionally its
>   subdirectories). All files found are filtered by an IOFileFilter. If
>   your search should recurse into subdirectories you can pass in an
>   IOFileFilter for directories. You don't need to bind a
>   DirectoryFileFilter (via logical AND) to this filter. This method does
>   that for you.
>
> An example: If you want to search through all directories called
>   "temp" you pass in FileFilterUtils.NameFileFilter("temp")

This returns a `Collection<File>`. Probably exactly what you want. Of course, if you need to  return an array, use `.toArray()` at the end.

If you really really have to use arrays, and it's still not homework, then you can concatenate two arrays, using Apache commons lang:

```
String[] both = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(first, second);
```

The above was copied from the answer to [How to concatenate two arrays in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java), which gives you all the answers you'll ever want.

Comment: I really do not think anyone should reinventing these kind of utilities. So, plus 1 to the suggestion of using FileUtils. Of course, the homework cavet withstanding. :)