# Is there a way to list all files recursively from a folder?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recursively list files in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java)

I think   File[] files = folder.listFiles() can only list the first level of files. Is there a way to list files recursively?

Comment: Yes. Write a recursive method.

Answer (score 2):

Not a built-in one, but you can write a short recursive program to do walk the directory tree recursively.

```
void listAll(File dir, List<File> res) {
    for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            listAll(f, res);
        } else {
            res.add(f);
        }
    }
}
```