# Calling GnuWin commands from Java or is there a better way?

Tags: java, runtime

i need to know if a specific string is contained in a list of files. The list of files is dynamic and i have to check a dynamic list of strings. This must be done in Java to work with the result (true or false). And MS Windows is also a requirement.

I thought about that problem i tried to use the unix way to do this:

```
find C:/temp | xargs grep import -sl
```

With GnuWin this works in cmd without any problems. So i tried to convert this into Java language. I read many articles about using Runtime class and ProcessBuilder class. But none of the tips are working. At last i tried the following two code snippets:

```
String binDir = "C:/develop/binaries/";

List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
command.add("cmd");
command.add("/c");
command.add(binDir+"find");
command.add("|");
command.add(binDir+"xargs");
command.add(binDir+"grep");
command.add("import");
command.add("-sl");

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.directory(new File("C:/temp"));
final Process proc = builder.start();

printToConsole(proc.getErrorStream());
printToConsole(proc.getInputStream());

int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
```

and

```
String binDir = "C:/develop/binaries/";
String strDir = "C:/temp/";

String[] command = {"cmd.exe ", "/C ", binDir + "find.exe " + strDir + " | " + binDir + "xargs.exe " + binDir + "grep.exe import -sl" };

Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = runtime.exec(command);

printToConsole(proc.getErrorStream());
printToConsole(proc.getInputStream());

int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
```

I also tried many other ways to concat the command, but either I get an error message (eg. file not found) or the process never comes back.

My questions:
1. Do you know a better way to do this job?
2. If not: Do you see any error in the code?
3. If not: Do you have another way i should try to run that command?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see your strDir in your first attempt. Is it a typo?

Comment: No, the strDir from second is set by `builder.directory(new File("C:/temp"));` in the first one.

Comment: Aren't you confusing strDir and binDir? Anyway, personnally I would rather try to do this with Java code and if necessary a Java library/framework which does the same as your cmd. Although I like Unix commands power, the code you are writing is not very robust and not much portable either.

Comment: Yes, i didn't understood your question right. Now i fixed my comment. :) I thought about reading all the files into java an searching "by hand". But the list of files can contain hundreds or thousands of files. Do you a framework for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's support for subprocesses is pretty weak, especially on Windows. Avoid using that API if you don't really *need* to.

Instead, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2056221/301832) discusses how to replace the `find` for the recursive search, and the `grep` should be easy enough (especially with [`FileUtil.readLines(…)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines(java.io.File)) to help).

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my head:

```
File yourDir = new File("c:/temp");
File [] files = yourDir.listFiles();
for(File f: files) {
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
     try {
         BuffereReaded reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis,"UTF-8")); // Choose correct encoding
         String s;
         while(((s=reader.readLine())!=null) {
             if (s.contains("import"))
              // Do something (add file to a list, for example). Possibly break out the loop
         }
     } finally {
           if (fis!=null)fis.close();
     }
}
```

Comment: You are aware that a POSIX `find` is recursive by default?

Comment: @DonalFellows yes :-) This was just a small piece of code to illustrate how I could do this. I don't think it is that difficult to use a recursive method.