# How to call doInBackground() recursively

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm currently trying to scan the file system for mp3 files. I did an `AsyncTask` that scans a directory and if finds a subfolder, it calls doInBackground() again for that subfolder and so on. However, this seems to crash the application. Is there any way to call `doInBackground()` recursively?

```
@Override
    protected List<File> doInBackground(String... params) {

        if (isCancelled()) return foundFiles_;
        publishProgress(String.valueOf(foundFiles_.size()));
        File file = new File(params[0]);
        String [] files = file.list();
        for(String fileName : files)
        {
            File foundFile = new File(fileName);
            if(foundFile.isDirectory())
            {
                doInBackground(fileName);
            }
            else
                foundFiles_.add(foundFile);
        }

        return foundFiles_;
    }
```

Comment: doInBackground() is just a method running in another thread, so you should be able to recursively calling him easily. Please, post some code to help you.

Comment: What error are you getting?, please post also logcat trace

Comment: here duplicated thread in same problem take look 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482204/how-to-recursively-scan-directories-in-android
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534632/list-all-files-from-a-directory-recursively-with-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to call doInBackground() recursively?

I would not do that. Instead, move your "scans a directory and if finds a subfolder" into some other method (e.g., `scanDirectory()`), which uses recursion. Then, have `doInBackground()` do the first call to your new method.