# Android - isDirectory always returns false for new File(pathToDirectoryString)

Tags: android, file, file-permissions

Our aim is to set readable and writable permissions on folders. using `[setReadable(bool)][1]` and `[setWritable(bool)][1]`. That is it.

We're already writing files to them and reading files from them, but as a precaution, we want to explicitly set these permissions.

The code is below. Does something get lost from `mkdirs()` to `getAbsolutePath()` to `new File` to `isDirectory()`? Because for some reason, when we check if the folderPath is a directory, it ALWAYS returns false, even though the log clearly identifies it as a path to a directory...

```
//This is in the onCreate function of the service.
File mainFolder = new File(thisService.this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "mainFolder");

if (!mainFolder.exists()) {
    //The folder doesn't exist yet, so create it.
    mainFolder.mkdirs();

    //And then make the other folders we'll need.
    File confsFolder = new File(File mainFolder.getAbsoluteFile()+"/confs");
    confsFolder.mkdirs();

    File logsFolder =new File(File mainFolder.getAbsoluteFile()+"/logs");
    logsFolder.mkdirs();

    File packagesFolder = new File(File mainFolder.getAbsoluteFile()+"/packages");
    packagesFolder.mkdirs();

    }

//String variables holding the folder paths.
confsFolderPathString = mainFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/confs/ ";
logsFolderPathString = mainFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/logs/ ";
packagesFolderPathString = mainFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/packages/ ";

setPermissions(new File(confsFolderPathString));
setPermissions(new File(logsFolderPathString));
setPermissions(new File(packagesFolderPathString));
```

...elswhere in the service...

```
private void setPermissions(File folderPath) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setPermissions: ");
    //Credit to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11482350/956975

    Log.d(TAG, "setPermissions: folderPath -> "+folderPath.getAbsoluteFile());
    //That log produces this strings:
    //setPermissions: folderPath -> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/our.package.domain.and.project/files/mainFolder/confs/ 
    //setPermissions: folderPath -> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/our.package.domain.and.project/files/mainFolder/logs/ 
    //setPermissions: folderPath -> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/our.package.domain.and.project/files/mainFolder/packages/ 
    //Those are DIRECTORIES, right?

    //Get the list of files (which could include folders) in the folderPath.

    if(folderPath.isDirectory()){ //<-------------THIS IS ALWAYS FALSE

        File[] list = folderPath.listFiles();

        if(list != null && list.length > 0){
             for (File f : list) {    
                 if (f.isDirectory()) {

                    Log.d("setPermissions: ", "Dir: " + f.getAbsoluteFile());

                    //Set readable permissions
                    f.setReadable(true);                        
                    //Set writable permissions
                    f.setWritable(true);

                    //Go deeper into the directory
                    setPermissions(f, true, true);

                    } else {
                        Log.d("setPermissions: ", "File: " + f.getAbsoluteFile());

                        //Set readable permissions
                        f.setReadable(true)
                        //Set writable permissions
                        f.setWritable(true);

                    }
                }
            }else{
                try {
                    throw new Exception("setPermissions: Directory list is empty.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "setPermissions: Directory list is empty.", e);
                }
            }
        }else{
            try {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("setPermissions: "+folderPath.getAbsolutePath() + " is not a directory.");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "setPermissions: "+folderPath.getAbsolutePath()+" is not a directory.", e);
            }
        }  
    }
```

Comment: `mainFolder.mkdirs();`. You should check the return value. Or again check if the directory exists. And if not return. Don't continue with the code if not. Display a Toast() saying so.

Comment: What sense does it make to set readable or writable  permissions on files or folders that you create yourself?

Comment: `if(folderPath.isDirectory()){ //<-------------THIS IS ALWAYS FALSE`. You should first check if that path exists(). If it does not exist it's because you did not check the return value of mkdirs().

Comment: You have also a mistake in the if of creation files. I have edited my answer. Check it

Comment: Good catch @adalPaRi !

Comment: ?????? `if (!File mainFolder.exists())` does not even compile. @adalPaRi

Comment: @greenapps I supposed xD

Comment: @greenapps, Why should I have to check for the existence of folderPath in the setPermissions function, if the check is done in onCreate already through mainFolder.exists()? Surely, the logic denotes that the directory should exist by the time it gets to the setPermissions function.

Comment: `Surely, the logic denotes that the directory should exist by the time it gets to the setPermissions function`. No it does not. And i told you why. Your code is insufficient. Unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is returning false because the directory does not exist yet when you call `isDirectory()`.

So, before check if it's a directoty, chec if exists:

```
private void setPermissions(File folderPath) {

    ...

    if(folderPath.exists() && folderPath.isDirectory()) {
      // ALL FUNCTIONALITY
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

You have a mistake in the if comprobation for create directories. You are checking `!File` instead of `!mainFolder.exists()`

```
if (!File mainFolder.exists()) {
```

replace it by

```
if (!mainFolder.exists()) {
```

Comment: I'm sorry to have caused confusion - I thought I had checked the content sufficiently before posting. I am doing if (!mainFolder.exists()) {. The original was probably a copy and paste error... Apologies.