# counting about of subfolders within subfolders

Tags: java, count, directory

I have a programme that sorts files into sub folders within a main file. I want to be able to print out in the console how many files are in each sub folder. Here is a example of my file structure.

> Main file → subfolder → folders I want to count

the subfolder could be any random number so i cannot use perticular file names on this folder. So what I need to do is look in the main file check how many subfolders there are and then get the names of the subfolders. Then go in the subfolders and get a count of how many folders are in there.

I hope you can help, I probably made this sound way harder than it is

Comment: You basically states exactly what you need to do yourself, so just start coding.

Comment: i havent yet found a solution @rogerGustavsson

Comment: Do you know how to read the contents of a file?

Comment: yes but dont know how to do both together in this context

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616124/get-number-of-files-in-a-directory-and-its-subdirectories first hit on google when searching "java count files in directory and subdirectories". Should have enough information.

Comment: If the file contains the name of a subfolder on each line, for each line read from file, look up subfolder on filesystem, scan subfolder for each file. Look into `java.io.*` or `java.nio.file.*` for classes on how to access the filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

Java 7 has a new IO package that supports Visitor pattern on file system tree of directories.  Take a look at this tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html