# listFiles - NullPointerException for c drive

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying to downgrade an application from Java 7 to Java 6 for the sake of compatibility. However, with Jave 6's listFiles() I get a NullPointerException for the c drive on Windows machines (and isHidden() returns true). Since Java 7's FileTreeWalker worked nicely, I'd assume it's not a Windows issue, is it? I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2056326/1856663) piece of code:

```
public class Filewalker {

    public void walk( String path ) {

        File root = new File( path );
        File[] list = root.listFiles();

        for ( File f : list ) {
            if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
                walk( f.getAbsolutePath() );
                System.out.println( "Dir:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() );
            }
            else {
                System.out.println( "File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() );
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Filewalker fw = new Filewalker();
        fw.walk("c:\\" );
    }
}
```

Bob

Comment: Which path did you exactly use, to list your files?

Comment: We can't really help you unless you show us the code that causes the problem.  (Showing us code that works is ... pointless)

Comment: OK, got it. the problem is that `listFiles("c:\\")` returns `null`. The NPE only occurs because you don't test for null.

Comment: you got 3 Options for this NPE.
 
1. your path does not exist

2. listfiles trys to list the Files of a file instead of a directory

3. An I/O happend

Comment: But even if I test for null, that doesn't get me the directory listing of the c drive. Strange enough, the code sample *is* for the c drive.

Comment: even so, you should use "C:/" instead of "C:\\", because the second solution is windows specific, the first one should be unsiversal

Comment: Did you check your permissions on C:/ drive. Sometimes if you are not an Administrative user. These sort of things can happen.

Comment: @Bob To access files on `C:` You need to have special permission life an admin.

Comment: @smit: But how does it come that Java 7 doesn't need these permissions?

Answer (score 2):

Try [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/), they might offer a cross JDK solution for your case.

[Update]
I ran your code and after checking with the JDK Documentation, `listFiles` returns null for paths that do not denote a directory, now looking at the code, despite the fact that you are checking if the current File is a directory prior to recursively calling walk, it turns out that at certain times a dir is mistaken for a file, It might be due to access permissions on Windows I'm not really quite sure why!

A note that lead me to think it has to do with permissions is that the dir that produced the `NullPointerException` was 'C:\Documents and Settings', calling `listFiles` on this path, returns null.

A temporary fix for the case would be to check if the file list is null or not.

Comment: As a fallback option: yes, but I'm right now I'm really just trying to find out what's wrong the c drive here.