# Java loop through files with the same name in a folder with subfolders

Tags: java, file, loops

I'm writing some Java code to loop through files with the same name in a folder with lots of subfolders, and do some logics on each file:

```
parentFolder/
            subfolder1/file.txt
            subfolder2/file.txt
            subfolder3/file.txt
            ... ...
            subfolderx/file.txt
```

above is the structure of what does it look like.

How would I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html may interest you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String parentFolderPath = "parentFolder";
String fileName = "file.txt";
File parent = new File(parentFolderPath);
for (File subFolder : parent.listFiles()) {
    if (subFolder.isDirectory()) {
        File f = new File(subFolder, fileName);
        if (f.exists()) {
            // your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Joe, this is exactly what I want to do! Cheers

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Java 7, you could try the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) implemented in the Path API: [`Files.walkFileTree(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.FileVisitor%29)

The simplest way to use it is to pass a (an anonymous) subclass of [`SimpleFileVisitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/file/SimpleFileVisitor.html) and do whatever you want whenever you visit a file. For example,

```
Files.walkFileTree(parentPath, new SimpleFileVisitor() {
  @Override FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
    // you can do whatever you want with "file" here.
    System.out.println("The file is: " + file);
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) class in Apache Commons.

They have [FileUtilsiterateFiles(File directory,IOFileFilter fileFilter,IOFileFilter dirFilter)](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#iterateFiles%28java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter%29) method where you can specify your file filters.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to throw out another way to do this. This file search and process software:
http://www.softpedia.com/get/File-managers/JFileProcessor.shtml
https://github.com/stant/jfileprocessor

Will let you search for files with glob or regex, in subfolders to X or all depth, by name, size, date. You can save to a List window or file.
Then you can run a groovy (think java) script to do whatever you want to the list of files; zip or tar them, modify the list strings like sed, delete, move, copy files, grep or ls -l them, whatever.
It will also let you massage your list like add to, delete from, subtract one list from another.