# How to go through folders and then write every file within those folders?

Tags: java, file, directory

How to go through folders and then write every file within those folders? If there is a folder within a folder we need to go through that first and then get back to the older directory.

Comment: What do you mean with "write every file"? What have you tried?

Comment: Try with a recursive method that uses [`File#listFiles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) and [`File#isDirectory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()). Come back when you have a real question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursively list files in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call a recursive function:

```java
public void writeStuff(final File file) {
    if(file.isDirectory()) {
        for(final File childFile : file.listFiles()) {
            writeStuff(childFile);
        }
    } else {
        //do stuff with file
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `else {` before the `// do stuff ` comment?

Comment: @MartinWilson fair point.

Comment: This is already covered in an answer on possible duplicate: [Recursively list files in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) based on the [FileVisitor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) interface that explains how one can go by.