# finding the sum of number dividsable by x using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I want to find the sum of numbers that is divisible by `x` using recursive method

> Ex if n= 10, x=3, the code should return sum of 3+6+9

Write a recursive method `sumDivByX(n, x)`, which finds the sum of all
numbers from `0` to n that are divisible by `x`.

I asked my teacher about it and he told me *"Firstly, total should be global.  You should return 0 if n or x == 0. I only care if n is divisible by x.  So I only add n to total (total+=n) if (n%x==0)  otherwise do nothing.  And do recursion sumDivByX(n-1,x) and return total as usual."* I tried to correct it.

```
public static int sumDivByX(int n, int x) {
    int total = 0;
    if (n == 0 || x == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (n % x >= 1) {
        return total = 0;
    } else if (n % x == 0) {
        return total += n;
    }
    return total + sumDivByX(n - 1, x);

}
```

When I run the program I get `0`.

Comment: Why is recursion a requirement?

Comment: return total + sumDivByX(n - 1, x); is unreachable

Comment: Telling students to write a recursive routine using a _global_ variable to accumulate the result?  Yeegaerargh.

Comment: The heck with recursion.  `return ((n / x) * (n / x + 1)) / 2 * x`;

Comment: @ajb your method works only for `n = a*x` with `a` a natural number

Comment: @Gee858eeG wrong!!!  Ever hear of "integer division"?

Comment: You're right. I forgot about that. Gj

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursively list files in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eliminate the returns inside your second and third `if` statements

```
public static int sumDivByX(int n, int x) {
    int total = 0;
    if (n == 0 || x == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n % x >= 1) {
        total = 0;
    } else if (n % x == 0) {
        total += n;
    }
    return total + sumDivByX(n - 1, x);

}
```

For a cuter, more compact version

```
public static int sumDivByX(int n, int x) {
    if (n == 0 || x == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (n % x == 0 ? n : 0) + sumDivByX(n - 1, x);
}
```

Note - depending on the semantics you intend, you might want to have separate checks for `x<=0` (possibly and error?) and `n==0` (base case).

Comment: I tested that code, and 3+6+9 should be 18 but it gives 17 instead, C.B. it would be fixed at returning 0 instead of -1 on 1st if

Comment: i tried to run the program by doing n=10 and x=3 the answer should be 18 but i get 17 @C.B

Comment: @user3469667 Depends on what you intend to happen. I've changed it to return 0 (base case), but if `x==0` is an error you should have that separeate

Comment: and since this answer is the one that works, I highly recommend @user3469667 that if any answer works for you, check them as accepted, it's a way of thanking people who helped you

Answer (score 0):

Step through your code and you'll see that it never recurses when n ==10 and x==3, since (10 % 3 == 1)

Answer (score 0):

When a method gets to a "return" statement it ends, in your case at the second if.

Your total is initialized by 0 everytime the method runs, so you should consider making it global.

Your method generates an exception if you try to use negative numbers as paramethers

Try this:

```
int total=0;
public static int subDivByX(int n, int X) {
   if (n>0 && x>0) {
      if (n%x==0){
          total += n;
      }
      return sumDivByX(n-1,x);
   } 
   else return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
private static int sumDivByX(int n,int x) {
    if (n < x || x < 1 ) {
        return 0;
    }
    int d = n/x;
    return (x * d) + sumDivByX(n - x , x);
}
```

*Recursion could cause a stackoverflow.*