# Is there a quick way to print the Textual representation of file structure?

Tags: java, eclipse, text, tree, file-structure

I'm working on a large project in Eclipse, and I'd like to quickly print out the file structure for various reasons, one of them being that I'd like to ask a question about it here on Stackoverflow.

For example, I'd like to print something like

```
my_proj
|--src
|   |-java
|   |   |-Hello.java
|   |   |-Goodbye.java
|   |
|   |-xml
|--res
|   |-html
|   |-css
....
```

etc....

Is there a quick way to generate this sort of representation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK Windows 8.1

Comment: check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/483326/equivalent-to-command-prompts-tree-command