# Search for file in a directory and its sub-directories

Tags: java

I would like to search all .txt files in a directory and its sub-directories.  This is what I so far.

```
package com.gm.scratchpad;

import java.io.File; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Arrays; 
import java.util.List;  

public class Main {     

    public static List<File> digFiles(File root, String typeOfFiles) {
        ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();  
        File[] files1 = root.listFiles();          
        return Arrays.asList(files1);     
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {         
        System.out.println("Hey, here are the files we dug!");
        System.out.println(digFiles(new File("C:/development/scratchpad/test/vinvRoot"),null));    
    } 
}
```

Comment: What does "inheritance" have to do with loops? Please clarify.

Comment: I think you want to recursively search... at least that's what I think you want.  What is your issue?

Comment: Yeah, I need to make a loop in my code, which continuously searches for all the directory, sub directory and gets all the .txt files

Comment: So can you update your title and question to make it more precise and clear?

Comment: have done it for you... next time please learn to ask in a smarter way, ok?

Comment: You do need to recursively search. You haven't shown any atempt at that yet.

Comment: and this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use `File.walkFileTree`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) for a description of how to use it.

Answer (score -1):

I am not going to give you actual code.  Here is a pseudo-code that should help.  It is the most naive way of implementing.  You should be able to improve it once you know how to implement:

```
List<File> findFiles(File directoryToSearch, String fileType) {
     List<File> result = ...;
     for each entry in directoryToSearch{
         if (entry is a directory) {
             result.addAll(findFiles(entry, fileType));
         } else if (entry is a file and entry is of fileType) {
             result.add(entry);
         }
     }
     return result;
}
```

Actually recursive directory walking is common and there is already a lot of utilities that can help.

Comment: Thank you sprinter and Adria Shum, this works.