# if Folder Contain File Then it Shows Else ignore in Java?

Tags: java, subdirectory

If Folder Contain File then only Display that Directory name in Java. how can we do that . as of now i am Getting Main Folder and Sub Folder name. please Find snapshot for better understanding

```
public class GetChild {


    private static FileFilter onlyDirectories = new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.isDirectory();
        }
    };
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        File currentDir = new File("E:\\Folder"); // current directory
        displayDirectoryContents(currentDir);
    }

    public static void displayDirectoryContents(File dir) {
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("");
       doDisplayDirectoryContents(dir, sb1);

    }

    private static void doDisplayDirectoryContents(File dir, StringBuilder sb1) {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles(onlyDirectories);
        for (File file : files) {
            try {
                System.out.println("file.getCanonicalPath()===>" + file.getCanonicalPath());
                doDisplayDirectoryContents(file, sb1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
      }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this Java 7+? If yes, any reason why you don't use java.nio.file?

Comment: i am Using Java 7  but i have perform more task with same code but initially this code creates problem . i want only SubFolder name thos who Contain any Files . better you see snapshot . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `FileFilter` and `File.listFiles()` to achieve this.

```
FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        return pathname.isFile();
    }
};
if (file.listFiles(filter).length > 0) {
    System.out.println("file.getCanonicalPath()===>" + file.getCanonicalPath());
else
    continue;
```

Comment: file.getCanonicalPath() give Same Folder Directory. please see my code once

Comment: @Jordi Castilla: :Your Code Return Only Sub Folder . i want to Access Some More Folder Inside Main Folder . if i want to access Folder and Sub Folder so only option is recursion . better you tell me if Folder Contain File then Show else ignore it . see my code it works Fine but it shows some Folder name those who does Not Contain any File . please Check once my Code and Snapshot . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are doing things in a really complicated way... hope this clarifies...

```
String filename = "myFile";
String folderPath = "E:\\Folder";

File folder = new File(folderPath);
File file = new File(folderPath, filename);

if (folder.exists() && folder.isDirectory() && file.exists() && file.isFile()) {
    // show file
} else {
    // error
}
```

If what you want is to explore all folders of a given one and see if there is files inside what you must use is **recursion**. Check [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/search-directories-recursively-for-file-in-java/) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2056326/3850595) sollutions...

**UPDATE:** here you have my sollution uising recursion and printing ONLY FOLDERS THAT CONTAINS FILES (NOT FOLDERS).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String folderPath = "C:\\Android";

        File folder = new File(folderPath);

        if (folder.exists())
            read(folder);
    }

    public static void read(File folder) {
        if (!folder.canRead() || folder.isFile()) return;
        File[] files = folder.listFiles();
        if (files.length < 1) return;
        boolean hasFile  = false;
        for (File f : files) {
            if (f.isDirectory())
                read(f);
            if (f.isFile())
                hasFile = true;
        }

        if (hasFile) System.out.println(folder.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Comment: Still i am getting same Path .

Comment: i want to print only Folder Name those who Contain File . i dont want to list of Files . here i am getting Some Folder Name Those Who not Contain File . see snapshot or code

Comment: Check updated Code with Snapshot For Better understand