# Right to Left DirectoryDialog in SWT

Tags: java, swt, right-to-left

I want to customize the DirectoryDialog in Right to Left mode. My question is:

1. Is there an easy way to do this?
2. Should I write it from scratch using [Recursively list files in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java). :|

Comment: Did you try to create the dialog with the ´RIGHT_TO_LEFT` style flag like so: `new DirectoryDialog( parent, SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT )`? Though this style flag is not documented, It may work nonetheless. If however this doesn't work, it is likely to be not supported.

Comment: it's not work. I think I should write it from scratch :(