# Searching for a specific file given a directory and filename, going down a directory and sending it's path

Tags: java, search

I've looked at [Recursively list files in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java) but this doesn't seem to solve my problem.
I've tried implementing it the way the answers have shown in this question but I my program still doesn't seem to work the way I want it to. It still doesn't "go down" the level if it finds a directory and sends that new directory path as an argument to check if file exists there.

I'm trying to get my class FileFinder to work.
Given a filename and a directory to start searching from I want to search and find the file with the filename.

I've created a sort of test directory in `/Users/Name/Documents/testing/`.
There is a file called "test.py" in one of the 3 directories under `/Documents/testing/`. But my program won't find the file. If I however give the method the proper directory like `/Documents/testing/correctDir/` it does find and print the file and it's path.

So I think my problem is when I find a directory the call to `fileFinder` doesn't work like it should. Am I dealing with "AbsolutePath" wrong in that line?

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class FileFinder {
    String fileFinder(String fileName, String root){
        String pathToFile = "";
        File rootDir = new File(root);
        File[] files = rootDir.listFiles();
        for(File f:files){
            if(f.isDirectory()){
                //System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
                fileFinder(fileName,f.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            else if(f.getName().equals(fileName)){
                pathToFile = f.getAbsolutePath();
            }
        }
        return pathToFile;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursively list files in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made two mistakes: first, you do not set `pathToFile` in the case of the recursive call to `fileFinder`. Second, you do not break the `for` loop when you have actually found the file in the directory you are currently looking in. Here's your code with the corrections, I've tested it and it works correctly:

```
String fileFinder(String fileName, String root){
    String pathToFile = "";
    File rootDir = new File(root);
    File[] files = rootDir.listFiles();
    for(File f:files){
        if(f.isDirectory()){
            //System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
            pathToFile = fileFinder(fileName,f.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        else if(f.getName().equals(fileName)){
            pathToFile = f.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        if (!pathToFile.isEmpty())
          break;
    }
    return pathToFile;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixed it!
Really appreciate the help @vagelis.