# How can i loop through A folder tree to generate a folder path?

Tags: java, c#, json, loops

I have this tree structure.

[FolderTree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/927DR.png)

How can i generate a folder path from it;

something like: folder1/chilfolder1/childfolder2/childfolder3

Do this for all folders in the tree :)

Comment: What did You try already ? Maybe recursion search ?

Comment: Yeah How can i do that ?

Comment: I think the best way is to search for some information, like this : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java
I've spend whole 5 seconds to get this topic ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recursively list all the files in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929276/how-to-recursively-list-all-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c)

Comment: please look at the image i sent with the question. I need to loop throught Json file wich contins folders with child folders.

Answer (score 0):

The objects that you are referring to as *files* and *folders* are just objects inside of a JSON serialized object. So, if you want to go about making `URIs` (Unique Resource Identifiers), you should analyze this data and go node by node down into the object, adding a `\` (path seperator) and a `String` value of the current node name.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be using a well-known depth-first search algorithm. Consider the following c# pseudo-code:

```
class Node {
   public string Name;
   public IEnumerbale<Node> Children;
}

void Main(){
   var tree = new List<Node>();//fill it somehow
   foreach(var node in tree){
      DFS(node);
   }
}

void DFS(Node root){
   foreach(var node in root.Children){
      node.Name = root.Name + '/' + node.Name;
      DFS(node);
   }  
}
```

After you run this code you'll get full names stored in `Name` property of each `Node`