# How to search Folder's sub folders Java

Tags: java, recursion

I have a folder which contains various subfolders (as seen in the graphic below). I am only interested in getting the list of contents for all subfolders labeled 'calculation'

**Visual Example:**

[image: File structure example]

So I want to start my search from root, recursively checking each directory. How can I accomplish this is Java 6?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Show us what you tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  File root = new File( path );
    File[] list = root.listFiles(); // you can also use listFileAndDirs()

    if (list == null) return;

    for ( File f : list ) {
        if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
        //check for the name of 'calculation' and traverse it recursive
```

for more info look at : [Recursively list files in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java)