# Java8 predicate with try catch

Tags: java-8, exception, java-stream

I'm a newbie of java8 streaming word, but I want to understand that.
After making some simple stuff, I went deeper, so I like to list all the files in a folder. I got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24006711/5349795).

```
    Files.walk(start)
        .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

It works well, but I ran that a folder, where some spec file are located, and throws `AccessDeniedException`. I made some search, and I know its not a simple problem. I try to handle the exception like this:

```
private static Predicate<Path> fillAccessDenied() {
    return p -> {
        try {
            if(Files.isRegularFile(p)) {                    
                return true;                
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (UncheckedIOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    };
}
  //....
    Files.walk(start)
        .filter(Utils.fillAccessDenied())
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

But the problem remains, and I don't understand why. Can somebody give me some clue what is the problem here?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I took the system out between a try catch, but the problem remains.

```
public static void println(Object x) {

    try {
        String s = String.valueOf(x);
        System.out.println(s);
    } catch (UncheckedIOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//...

    Files.walk(start)
        .filter(Utils.fillAccessDenied())
        .forEach(Utils::println);
```

My input path "/" and I run it on linux. Does it cause this problem?

**stacktrace:**

```
java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /etc/sysconfig/network/providers
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.fetchNextIfNeeded(FileTreeIterator.java:88)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.hasNext(FileTreeIterator.java:104)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:115)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at hu.gergelylakatos.jbackupper.JBackupper.main(JBackupper.java:45)
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /etc/sysconfig/network/providers
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:427)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:457)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:300)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.next(FileTreeWalker.java:372)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.fetchNextIfNeeded(FileTreeIterator.java:95)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: You're still getting AccessDenied on files that are 'regular'. You could just add a method for printing, with a try catch and use that in your foreach

Comment: @dustytrash thx but did not fix the problem

Comment: Change the catch to be a `AccessDeniedException`

Comment: My input path "/" and I run it on linux. Does it cause this problem?

Comment: @dustytrash I got `Unreachable catch block for AccessDeniedException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body`

Comment: I think the exception occurs when you're working with a folder, not a file. I'll update my answer

Comment: Can you include the stack trace? You have to catch the exception where it is thrown. If `Files.isRegularFile` doesn’t throw that exception, there is no sense in trying to catch it there.

Comment: @Holger I included the trace. Thanks for the help.
@dustytrash I extended with `&& !Files.isDirectory(p)`

Now I made it the "old fashion way" so I try to catch my bug. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not catch the exception at `Files.isRegularFile` when it isn’t thrown at this place. Since the exception is thrown inside the code implementing iteration logic of `Files.walk`, you can only catch it at the `forEach` method, when it has already terminated the entire operation.

You may implement the iteration logic yourself to have more control. E.g.

```
public static Stream<Path> traverse(Path p, BiConsumer<Path,IOException> handler) {
    if(Files.isDirectory(p)) try {
        return Stream.concat(Stream.of(p),
            Files.list(p).flatMap(sub -> traverse(sub, handler)));
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        handler.accept(p,ex);
    }
    return Stream.of(p);
}
```

which you may use like

```
traverse(start, (p,ex) -> System.err.println(p+": "+ex))
    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

to print the exception and continue, or

```
traverse(start, (p,ex) -> { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); })
    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

to bail out like `Files.walk`.

---

When you know that you are interested in regular files only, you can create a specialized method like

```
public static Stream<Path> traverseLeafs(Path p, BiConsumer<Path,IOException> handler) {
    if(Files.isDirectory(p)) try {
        return Files.list(p).flatMap(sub -> traverseLeafs(sub, handler));
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        handler.accept(p,ex);
        return Stream.empty();
    }
    return Stream.of(p);
}
```

which excludes directories right at the source. You may still use `filter(Files::isRegularFile)` though, to exclude special files which are neither directory nor regular file.

You may also use `Files.isDirectory(p) && Files.isReadable(p)` as condition here, to prevent the `AccessDeniedException` from occurring, at least as long as the access flags do not change between `Files.isReadable(p)` and `Files.list(p)`.

Comment: Its working. Thank you so much, its a nice explanation, I can understand the problem now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change your filter. Checking if the file `isRegular`, doesn't mean you won't get the `AccessException`.

Ensure you're filtering out folders.

```
private static Predicate<Path> fillAccessDenied() {
    return p -> {
        try {
            if(Files.isReadable(p) && !Files.isDirectory(p)) {                    
                return true;                
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (UncheckedIOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, I changed the condition but the problem remains. I changed the system out as well, check the updated question.