# In Java 7, list files with "relative path"

Tags: java, unix, directory, java-7

Given the below directory structure:

```
/dir1
/dir1/dir2
/dir1/dir2/file1
/dir1/dir2/file2
/dir1/dir2/dirA/file3
```

someFunction("dir2")

desired output:

```
dir2/file1
dir2/file2
dir2/dirA/file3
```

I am using FileUtils.listFiles and Paths and then String manipulation, but wondering if better way. Just seems convoluted.

The Unix command *find dir2* is pretty spot on.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash A List of Strings shown above, or Paths or Files.

Comment: Check if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a base directory and a `Collection<File>`. You can use `Path.relativize` to get the relative path from one to the other.

This example, given `/dir1` and `/dir1/foo/bar/baz`, will result in `foo/bar/baz` without any fragile string operations:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Path base = Paths.get("/dir1");
    File f = new File("/dir1/foo/bar/baz");
    System.out.println(base.relativize(f.toPath()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Solution using relativize method removes need for string manipulation and regex.

Comment: What is the reason for mixing `File` and `Path`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the Java 7 [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html), you might as well use the Java 7 [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) too.

```
static void someFunction(String dir) throws IOException {
    Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(dir), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            System.out.println(file);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
}
```

*Test*

```
someFunction("dir2");
```

*Output (on Windows<sup>1</sup>)*

```
dir2\dirA\file3
dir2\file1
dir2\file2
```

<sup>*1) On Linux, the paths would have forward slash instead of backslash.*</sup>