# Java- Recursively Get the path of directorys with files on it

Tags: java, directory, subdirectory

How do i recursively get the path of directorys with files on it?

Im writing a program that needs to get the path of all the directories with JAVA files on it, recursively, for example:

```
|   |-->Foo2 --> lore.java
|Foo|
|   |-->Foo3 --> Foo4 --> ipsum.java
```

In this example, I would want to save in a list: FOO/FOO2 and FOO/FOO3/FOO4. There may be more nested directories, and those directories might contain java files, an example might be:

```
|
|   |--> Foo2 --> lore.java
|   |
|Foo|         | --> ipsum.java
|   |--> Foo3 |
|   |         | --> Foo4 --> rosae.java
```

In this example, i would want to save FOO/FOO2, FOO/FOO3 and FOO/FOO3/FOO4.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `Files.walk()` API introduced in Java 8 should be your friend here, check 
the related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/24006711/4292075 and https://mkyong.com/java/java-files-walk-examples/ for examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if the following will work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Path> listOfDirectoryPaths = new ArrayList<>();

        try (Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(Paths.get("."))) {
            walk.forEach(path -> {
                if(path.toFile().isFile() && path.toFile().getName().contains(".java")) {
                    listOfDirectoryPaths.add(path.getParent());
                }
            });

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(listOfDirectoryPaths.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

This will traverse the current directory (.) of where you run it from.
It will look for files that contain ".java"
It will store the Path of the Dir.
Finally, it will return only the distinct paths, so you dont get duplicates.

Try it, and modify it as you see fit.