# Foreach in JSP to look more directory

Tags: file, jsp, foreach

I want to get all the file names in a JSP's server directory, and to do that i thought that it would be need some `foreach` statement, how to do that?

Comment: this solution could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/q/947730/778687

Comment: how to do 'foreach directory' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
File file = new File(request.getRealPath(request.getServletPath()));
File[] fileList = file.getParentFile().listFiles();
```

You can iterate over this `fileList` like this:

```
for (File file : fileList) {
  // Do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: is it possible to do foreach statement for those file lists? like `foreach file`