# Java JSP - Remove .DS_Store and show correct folder names

Tags: java, html, jsp

so Im working on viewing files within A JSP page. However, any folders within a directory only appear as '.DS_Store' Rather than showing all folders with their correct names. I nhave used this code from this thread:
 [How to list contents of a server directory using JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947730/how-to-list-contents-of-a-server-directory-using-jsp)

The code:

```
<table class="main" id="tableMain">
<thead>
<th scope="col">First</th>
<%@page import="java.io.*" %> 
<%@page import="java.util.*" %> 

<%!        public void GetDirectory(String a_Path, Vector a_files, Vector a_folders) {
            File l_Directory = new File(a_Path);
            File[] l_files = l_Directory.listFiles();

            for (int c = 0; c < l_files.length; c++) {
                if (l_files[c].isDirectory()) {
                    a_folders.add(l_files[c].getName());
                } else {
                    a_files.add(l_files[c].getName());
                }
            }


        }
    %> 

    <%
        Vector l_Files = new Vector(), l_Folders = new Vector();
        GetDirectory("/Library/Tomcat/webapps/HelloServlet/uploads", l_Files, l_Folders);




        for (int a = 0; a < l_Files.size(); a++) {
            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td>" + l_Files.elementAt(a).toString() + "</td>");
            out.println("</tr>");
        }

    %>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, you're viewing the contents of an empty directory? .DS_Store files are automatically generated on MacOS by finder. It's basically an index file that contains preview pictures and metadata for the current directory. They exist in a directory that you have opened with finder before, I believe.

In the case that you're only seeing suhc a file in a directory, I would suspect it is because the directory is empty except for that file.

For debugging purposes, you could also render the absolute path of files and directories shown (use *.getAbsolutePath()* instead of *.getName()*) That might give you a better indication on what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt remove the .DS_Store directory, however it lists folders within the directory as well as files:

```
String file = application.getRealPath("/safe");
File f = new File(file);
String [] fileNames = f.list();
File [] fileObjects= f.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < fileObjects.length; i++) {
    if(!fileObjects[i].isFile() || !fileObjects[i].isDirectory()){
    String fname = file+fileNames[i];
    out.print("<tr>");
    out.println("<td>" + fileNames[i] + "</td>");
    out.print("</tr>");
```